# MySQL: LEFT JOIN not working as expected

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables: Employees, attendanceIn
[image]

When I query using LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT employees.eno,employees.name,employees.dept,attendanceIn.attIn FROM `employees` 
LEFT JOIN attendanceIn ON employees.eno = attendanceIn.eno
WHERE date(attIn) like '2016-07-02%'
```

What I got is,

[image: Actual result]

- Whats wrong with my Query?
- How do I get my Expected result?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `WHERE date(attIn) like '2016-07-02%'` is converting the `LEFT` join to an `INNER` join. The condition should be moved to the `ON` clause.

Also:

- It's not good practise to use `LIKE` for dates comparison
- Using functions on columns (like the `date()`) before comparing it makes indexes useless. It's better to make the condition **[sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)**.

The query corrected:

```
SELECT e.eno, e.name, e.dept, a.attIn 
FROM employees AS e 
  LEFT JOIN attendanceIn AS a 
    ON  e.eno = a.eno
    AND a.attIn >= '2016-07-02'
    AND a.attIn  < '2016-07-03' ;
```

Tested at [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcc4bc/1).

Comment: I was facing the similar issue. The solution worked for me. But I didn't get the logic behind your statement that that particular condition in where clause is converting it from left to inner join

Answer (score 1):

Your `LEFT JOIN` delivers the missing `attendanceIn` fields as `NULL`. If you still want this result then you must add:

```
or attIn is NULL
```

at the end of your query. Now you will get the expected result.