# MySQL LEFT JOIN, returning data for 0/1 values vs. NULL values

Tags: mysql, join, select

Have this MySQL SELECT query:

```
SELECT product.id, product.name, shop.currency, price.amount, shop.name
FROM product LEFT JOIN price ON product.id = price.product_id
LEFT JOIN shop ON price.shop_id = shop.id
WHERE price.active = 1 OR price.active IS NULL
```

Works great if price.active = 1 or if there is any price (which ok, that's the reason for the LEFT JOIN).

Problem is if there's a price and price.active = 0. In that case, nothing is returned.

If there is a price and price.active = 0, how can I make the SELECT return data in the same way as if there isn't any price?

i.e. like this:

- price.active = NULL - return data, empty shop.currency, empty price.amount and shop.name
- price.active = 1 - return data, including shop.currency, price.amount and shop.name
- price.active = 0 - return data, empty shop.currency, empty price.amount and shop.name

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL: LEFT JOIN not working as expected](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/143090/mysql-left-join-not-working-as-expected) Change `WHERE ...` to `AND (price.active = 1 OR price.active IS NULL)` ie make it part of the `ON` clause

Comment: It does! Thanks Charlieface.