# SQL query - left join between two tables a,b to pull out data from a which doesn't exist in b since last x days

Tags: mysql

Let's say we're dealing with a simple social network where we have two tables

- Students
- Posts

I'm trying to pull out data of those Students who haven't made any post in past X days - given I have a list of few students to search for.

I've tried the below approach but it isn't giving me results :

```
select s.id, s.uid from students s left join 
posts p
on s.id = p.student_id
where s.is_active=1 and s.uid in ('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL')
and p.created_at > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY)
and p.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Answer (score 1):

Your primary issue is that you have the `created_at` condition in the `WHERE` rather than the `ON` clause. This effectively [turns your query into an `INNER JOIN`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/143096/220697).

```
select s.id, s.uid
from students s
left join posts p
    on s.id = p.student_id
    and p.created_at > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY)
where s.is_active = 1
  and s.uid in ('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL')
  and p.id IS NULL;
```

But you could more elegantly represent this as an anti-join, using `NOT EXISTS`

```
select s.id, s.uid
from students s
where s.is_active = 1
  and s.uid in ('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL')
  and not exists (select 1
    from posts p
    where s.id = p.student_id
      and p.created_at > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY)
);
```